# What's the difference between the Samsung 840 Series SSD and the 840 EVO-Series SSD?

Tags: ssd

The [Samsung 840 SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009NHAEXE) seems identical to the [Samsung 840 EVO-Series SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E3W15P0) except for the color and the price. What's the difference? Research has yielded nothing but there must be a reason as the EVO is almost $10 more.

Comment: The EVO has some SLC cache and lets you use your system ram to speed it up. http://techreport.com/review/25282/a-closer-look-at-rapid-dram-caching-on-the-samsung-840-evo-ssd <- thats a good overview. And as always check out anandtech, who also have reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 840 uses TLC (triple-level cell) while the Evo uses [multi-level cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) with the mentioned SLC cache. The MLC improves the durability.

Comment: This is incorrect. The 840 EVO still uses TLC. The Pro drives use (2-bit) MLC.

Answer (score 2):

It does not, contrary to the answer above, use "MLC" (2-bit). TLC refers to 3-bit MLC, which is still used on the 840 EVO.

[Anandtech was fairly thorough reviewing the EVO](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7173/samsung-ssd-840-evo-review-120gb-250gb-500gb-750gb-1tb-models-tested/). More cache, cache is now (faster) SLC, updated controller, SATA 3.1 (TRIM queuing). Uses a bit more power, gets faster.